# Perform left join with Include() with Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm facing an issue with Entity Framework Core in C#. I have created a function to return the list of `Organisation` from my database. For each organisation, I have two tables:

- `OrganisationUser`: the link with `Organisation` is the *OrganisationId*. This table is linked to the `Licence` table with the *LicenceId*
- `Invitation` the link with `Organisation` is the *OrganisationId*. This table is linked to the `Licence` table with the *LicenceId*

If I run the query I received, as I expected, the list of organisations with all details.

```
public IQueryable<Organisation> GetOrganisationsByBillingDay(int billingDay)
{
    return _context.Organisation
                   .Include(org => org.OrganisationUser)
                        .ThenInclude(usr => usr.License)
                   .Include(org => org.Invitation)
                        .ThenInclude(i => i.License)
                   .Where(o => o.BillingDay == billingDay);
}
```

In this list the organisation that doesn't have any records in `OrganisationUser` or `Invitation` are excluded.

How is it possible to include them? Is there a diffrent way than writing a query with `Linq`?

### Update

If you look at the query Linq creates it ia a left join.

[image]

The configuration is

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BillingContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("BillingDatabase"),
    providerOptions => providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure()
));
```

### Last Update

As you can see in the screenshot, `Linq` performs *left join* queries. I have now what I'm looking for. The problem was in the data not in the code.

Comment: How is the context configured? `Include` doesn't perform joins, it tells EF Core to use eager loading to load related entities. Without it you can still load those items while the context is still alive, simply by accessing the relevant properties. It's the DbContext configuration that controls what queries are created

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Include()` can generate joins, indeed that's what I see in our EF core models most of the itme, but it is an implementation detail I guess.

Comment: Is the relation defined as optional or required? One-to-One, one-to-many?

Comment: @TanveerBadar that doesn't mean it's used for joining, or that it should be used if someone wants to join. There are a *lot* of SO questions asking `why didn't Include() generate a JOIN ?`. In most cases, there's no relation configured in the DbContet

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you look the generated sql from Linq, you can see the join.

Comment: Yes, I know. But `Include` isn't meant to JOIN, it's meant to eagerly load data *based on the entity configurations*. Without a configured relation (explicitly or through conventions), it won't join anything. The way eager loading works is by using JOINs to get all data in a single query, even if that means duplicating the "root" entity

Comment: Post your entity configuration code. Perhaps the relation is configured as a `Required` one, in which case an `INNER JOIN` is used, eliminating parent entities with no children. For Optional relations a `LEFT JOIN` would be used instead. What if you *don't* use `Include()`? Can you load the entities lazily?

Comment: The query you posted uses LEFT JOINs, so the only way for it to return no data would be if there was no matching data. Have you tried running that query in SSMS? Do the individual queries return what you expected? Without sample data that reproduces the problem people have to guess

Comment: For example, that query shows a join between `o.id` and `t.organisation_id`. Those aren't the names of any properties mentioned in the question. Again, post your entities and context configuration. I assume aliasing and mapping is configured correctly? In that case, have you tried a three-way merge between `organisation`, `organisation_users` and `license` using the fields in that query? Do you get any data?

Answer (score 0):

If it is optional, then your navigation property will either be null or an empty collection depending upon what the cardinality of relationship is. There is nothing special you need to do as the join is implied by `Include()` but not explicitly specified by the user in the query itself.

The most likely issue is your relationship definition. Can you share your model config?

Comment: Sorry, what part? `DbContext` settings? `Organisation` model?

Comment: That would be the stuff you were putting in your `OnModelCreating()` method, or if it is by conventions then share entity definitions. And like people said in comments to your question, LEFT JOIN will return 0 rows only when there is nothing inthe table itself.